# The meaning given to "coalesce" in sql

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, programming

I'm a software developer and a linguistics fan. In SQL syntax, there's a command named `COALESCE`, which does a simple thing (quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366500/3002584)):

> It simply goes through all the parameters one by one, and returns the
>   first that is NOT NULL.
>
> ```
> COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 3)
> => 1
>
>
> COALESCE(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NULL)
> => 1
> ```

From what I see in dictionaries, "Coalesce" means "unite", or "blend", or "merge", etc. I can't see the connection between those definitions to `COALESCE` operation.

Is there another meaning to this word?

Edit: Thanks to [Janus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372493/the-meaning-given-to-coalesce-in-sql#comment871947_372493) comment, I searched a bit more and found a similiar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770186/null-coalescing-operator-what-does-coalescing-mean#) on StackOverflow answering this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @HotLicks The OP is asking an interesting English question. I see no reason to close and he has done research.

Comment: @k1eran - The OP is asking about a specific use of a keyword in a computer language.  This has nothing to do with English.

Comment: @HotLicks although it is used as a keyword, it doesn't mean it isn't an English word with a meaning. I think the OP has sufficiently made the question English-related.

Comment: @HotLicks He is obviously clear on how it works in the computer language. I interpret this an etymology question - why coalesce fits well for this particular mathematical/logical/computing usage.

Comment: This would be off-topic on SuperUser anyway @HotLicks

Comment: This isn't just SQL, one might add. The general term for this functionality is [_null coalescing operator_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) (though in SQL it's a function, rather than an operator as in most languages).

Comment: Think of *coalesce* as *come together*.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course it’s a question about about the English language. It is asking what sense of the word `coalesce` applies in this case. Your reply to @k1eran shows a misunderstanding of the question. It is _not_ a question about using the word in a computer language, but about what meaning of the word is applied.

Comment: I think you will find that in Mathematics in general, and programming languages in particular, tend to use English (or other language) words in a convoluted way. There might be a primary meaning which leads to a secondary meaning which leads to something purely tangental. Sometimes involving certain substances on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coalesce) has two definitions:

> 1. Come together to form one mass or whole:
>      *‘the puddles had coalesced into shallow streams’*
> 2. **[with object] Combine (elements) in a mass or whole:
>
>      *‘his idea served to coalesce all that happened into one connected whole’***
>
> [...]   Origin
>   Mid 16th century: 
>   from Latin coalescere grow together, from co- (from cum with) + alescere grow up (from alere nourish).
>
> — [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coalesce)

I think the latter one *[with object]* applies well since the computing usage has an object (i.e. the parameters) which are indeed combined into a single mass/whole.

In the computing context, there are detailed rules as to **how** the elements are combined - but that is arguably a 'computing detail'.

Comment: I think you're right, but it's a tenuous connection with the operation. I imagine them going through a dictionary looking for a word with a meaning somewhere near what they needed, and settling on _coalesce_ because they couldn't find anything better.

Comment: The SQL function is really a shorthand name for _null-coalescence_. I'd say this is exactly right: null-coalescence is a subtype of the highlighted meaning here. The difference is only that the two elements used to form the resulting whole are not _combined_ as such, but compared and selected from: if the first element is `NULL` (i.e., pure nothingness), it is ignored; otherwise, the second element is ignored. So essentially it ‘coalesces’ (subsumes) null into the other element. It is a bit of a stretch of the original meaning, but definitely does seem to be a development based on it.

Comment: I would construe it to mean that all the *NULL*s are coalesced into nothingness leaving the first element to be the first non-null.  I hadn’t thought about those nulls being coalesced ***into*** that first element.  But the result is equivalent.